Need ideas to build a recipient list like Gmail in Vue3
I wanted to build a recipient list like in Gmail using Vue3 recently but I am out of idea on how to accomplish this and I can't seem to find good ressources online.
recipient list
I have an array of string that contains the emails and I can loop over them to display them in a div. But how do I know when I reach the end of the div and that I have to remove the email?
Then, each hidden emails would be counted and shown as a badge. No badge is shown if all emails fit in the box of course.
Thank you for your guidance!
I did not try anything yet as I do not even know where to start with this.
Should I get the width of the container div, but then how do I know when a children div containing an email reaches the end of the parent?

You can get the width  of each email-string and measure, if it fits into the parent container

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Initially, the width of the email container is measured. Subsequently, whenever there's a change in the email array or the browser width, each email element is measured. This measurement adjusts the email array (with slice()), ensuring that sliced emails fit within the email container div.
You can run this example that I've made:


const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      emails: [],
      renderedEmails: [],
      hiddenCount: 0,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    measureRecipientList() {
      const tolerance = 50
      const containerWidth =
        document.getElementById('email-container').offsetWidth + tolerance
      let totalWidth = 0
      let countDisplay = -1
      setTimeout(() => {
        const hiddenEmailDivs =
          document.getElementsByClassName('hidden-email')
        for (const el of hiddenEmailDivs) {
          if (totalWidth < containerWidth) {
            totalWidth += el.clientWidth
            countDisplay += 1
          }
        }
        if (totalWidth > containerWidth) {
          countDisplay -= 1
        }
        this.renderedEmails = this.emails.slice(0, countDisplay)
        this.hiddenCount = this.emails.length - countDisplay
      })
    },
    onWidthChange() {
      this.measureRecipientList()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.onWidthChange);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.emails = [
        'email1@example.com',
        'email2@example.com',
        'email3@example.com',
        'email4@example.com',
        'email5@example.com',
        'email6@example.com',
        'email7@example.com',
        'email8@example.com',
        'email9@example.com',
        'email10@example.com',
      ]
    }, 500) // simulate loading 500 ms
  },
  unmounted() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.onWidthChange);
  },
  watch: {
    emails() {
      this.measureRecipientList()
    },
  },
})
  
app.mount("#app")
#email-container {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 25px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.email {
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.hidden-email {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: pink;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#badge {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}
<div id="app">
<div>Recipient List:</div>
  <div id="email-container">
    <div class="email" v-for="(email, index) in renderedEmails" :key="index">
      {{ email }}
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-email" v-for="(email, index) in emails" :key="index">
      {{ email }}
    </div>
    <div id="badge">
      {{ hiddenCount }} more
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.8/vue.global.min.js"></script>



